# Подскажите базовый принцип интефейса в Kotlin на моём примере

Tags: android, kotlin

В примере базовый каркас приложения по работе с GPS.

Вопрос по инициализации переменной locListenerInterface в классе GpsClass.
Как понять концептуально, что мы присваиваем этой переменной при определении?

```
private var locListenerInterface: LocListenerInterface = (myContext as LocListenerInterface)
```

Работает так же

```
private var locListenerInterface: LocListenerInterface = (myContext as MainActivity)
```

Как вообще правильно инициализировать эту переменную, для передачи координат в MainActivity с класса GpsClass через интерфейс LocListenerInterface

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LocListenerInterface {
    private val gps = GpsClass(this)
    override fun onLocationChangedInterface(location: Location) {
        // show updated location
    }
}

interface LocListenerInterface  {
    fun onLocationChangedInterface (location: Location)
}

class GpsClass (private val myContext: Context) {
    private var locListenerInterface: LocListenerInterface = (myContext as LocListenerInterface)
    fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        locListenerInterface.onLocationChangedInterface(location)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locListenerInterface у Вас типа LocListenerInterface. Поэтому присвоить ему нужно объект соответствующего типа. Вернее в данном случае объект реализующий интерфейс LocListenerInterface.

myContext у Вас типа Context. Скорее всего Context не наследует/реализует LocListenerInterface. Поэтому просто присвоить myContext в locListenerInterface  Вы не можете. Компилятор выдаст ошибку.

Но Вы, как разработчик, знаете что реально внутри в myContext у Вас будет объект, который реализует/наследует и Context и LocListenerInterface. Поэтому Вы явно пишете компилятору считать myContext реализующим LocListenerInterface через ключевое слово as. Компилятор это компилирует, но также внутри добавляет код который проверяет в рантайме правда ли то, что пришло в myContext, реализует LocListenerInterface и если нет будет ошибка выполнения

И писать нужно именно так как в первом примере кода

Второй пример с MainActivity работает потому, что, по сути, внутри происходит как бы два преобразования - вначале вы явно приводите myContext к типу MainActivity, но компилятор видит что MainActivity реализует LocListenerInterface и неявно приводит еще раз MainActivity уже к LocListenerInterface и все опять компилируется.

Comment: Спасибо.  Достаточно понятно.

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него. Так же в качестве рекомендации к будущим вопросам могу посоветовать не использовать метку android-studio в вопросах не связанных непосредственно с IDE :D

Comment: Можно ли было по другому переменной locListenerInterface присвоить объект, реализующий интерфейс LocListenerInterface? Не через Context? Или код в примере достаточно корректный?

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии  это зависит от задачи. Желательно использовать Depedency Injection -  почитайте про Dagger и Hilt